# firebase-tools "Error: certificate has expired"

Tags: firebase, command-line-interface, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

This morning I tried to deploy my react project to firebase hosting but I received this error:

```
Error: Server Error. certificate has expired
```

Then I tried to execute `firebase list` command to see the list of my projects but again I received the same error! I tried it on other projects with the same result. So I believe this error is not related to a specific project and it has something to do with `firebase-tools`. Here is the error log:

```
[debug] 
[debug] [2020-01-07T03:37:57.789Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2020-01-07T03:37:57.789Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2020-01-07T03:37:57.792Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects  

[debug] [2020-01-07T03:37:58.566Z] Error: certificate has expired
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1116:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:643:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:473:38)
[error] 
[error] Error: Server Error. certificate has expired
```

Comment: If you have a problem running the Firebase CLI to interact with your projects, please contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the solution. First, do this:

```
npm i -g firebase-tools@latest
```

It looks like I'm using an outdated version of Firebase CLI. This error happened because the older versions of CLI are linked to legacy Firebase services that are no longer operational. Upgrading to the latest CLI version is the only solution.

Then you need to use new commands instead of deprecated ones. For example:

```
firebase projects:list  //instead of firebase list
```

Comment: npm i -g firebase-tools@latest - Tried but still same error.

Comment: had to reopen the terminal in mac.

Comment: upgrading firebase ask me to upgrade node as well. my project is using node 6.14.0.
When i upgrade node, project breaks! how can we make it work with node 6?

Answer (score 4):

Probably you will need:

```
sudo npm i -g firebase-tools@latest --force
```

Answer (score 3):

I updated to latest and did logout+login.
Only started working after closing the terminal and opening a new one

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.
Change your local clock to before 4th of January 2020

Comment: @jan-kremen, what do you mean by "change your local clock"?

Answer (score 1):

I had an old version of `firebase` installed that was not allowing the new CLI to run correctly. I had to manually delete the old version, reinstall the new version, and then everything worked fine. Here's how I did it:

1. Run `which firebase` in your terminal to see where your firebase npm package is saved.
2. Delete that folder.
3. Run `npm i -g firebase-tools@latest`
4. Run `firebase init` and you should be up and running again without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

run `npm install --save firebase-functions@latest` and make sure to add

```
"engines": {
  "node": "8" 
}
```

in your package.json

Answer (score 0):

If issue still exist after updating the CLI then try to logout from firebase and re-login

```
firebase logout
firebase login
```