# Starting a new project locally with "firebase init" gives "Server Error. certificate has expired"

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I'm trying to setup a completely new project in a new folder in Mac OS by running:

```
firebase init
```

And I always get the same error:

> Error: Server Error. certificate has expired

I tried different things as mentioned in [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621948/firebase-tools-error-certificate-has-expired) like:

```
npm i -g firebase-tools@latest
sudo npm i -g firebase-tools@latest
npm install --save firebase
```

Nothing helped. Sharing **firebase-debug.log** below:

```
[debug] [2020-02-02T21:27:36.490Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2020-02-02T21:27:36.493Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase init hosting
[debug] [2020-02-02T21:27:36.493Z] CLI Version:   3.18.5
[debug] [2020-02-02T21:27:36.493Z] Platform:      darwin
[debug] [2020-02-02T21:27:36.493Z] Node Version:  v10.16.0
[debug] [2020-02-02T21:27:36.500Z] Time:          Sun Feb 02 2020 22:27:36 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
[debug] [2020-02-02T21:27:36.500Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2020-02-02T21:27:36.511Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"]
[debug] [2020-02-02T21:27:36.512Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[info] 
                      
                                               
                      
                                               
                               

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  /Users/user/apps/laisvi

[info] 
=== Project Setup
[info] 
[info] First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
[info] You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
[info] but for now we'll just set up a default project.
[info] 
[debug] [2020-02-02T21:27:36.519Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects  

 Sun Feb 02 2020 22:27:36 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
[debug] [2020-02-02T21:27:37.059Z] Error: certificate has expired
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1055:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:633:8)
[error] 
[error] Error: Server Error. certificate has expired
```

I think it's a different problem, maybe related with rights on Linux? Anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: If the Firebase CLI gives you an error that is not obvious to resolve, you should contact Firebase support for assistance. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson, I did, but still waiting for the response.

Comment: you can spect an answer in the week :)

Comment: Thank you @GastónSaillén

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FOUND THE RESOLUTION!**

The problem was that I installed firebase using old documentation and it was linked to `firebase` command ignoring the `firebase-tools` which didn't get any alias by default. My steps:

**Step 1:** Locate firebase:

```
which firebase
```

**Step 2:** Delete firebase

```
rm // whatever location it gave you which firebase
```

**Step 3:** Install *again* firebase-tools (might not have been necesary)

```
npm i -g firebase-tools@latest
```

**Step 4:** Create an alias to the tools

```
alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
```

You can now do `firebase init` and finally create a firebase project with vanilla Js!

Comment: This works! alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"